# C# Create instance, call method and assign return variable in one line

Tags: c#, instantiation, one-liner, multiple-variable-return

Assume the following code:

```
DeviceCommunicationDao dao = new DeviceCommunicationDao();
var device = dao.GetDeviceById(123); //returns an object of type "Device"
```

So I want to assign **2 variables**. Is there a way to do this in one line? I mean generally, like via a generic extension method?
Something like this:

```
var device = (new DeviceCommunicationDao() as DeviceCommunicationDao dao).GetDeviceById(123);
```

I am not looking for lectures on how this is a bad idea and what is confusing or not. I am looking for a one-liner that instantiates 2 variables with a generic approach.
Cheers!

Comment: What is wrong with the first snippet?

Comment: You can create a function that returns a tuple or has an out argument

Comment: either your function returns a `DeviceCommunicationDao` or a `Device`. Mixing both into a single method leads to more confusion than it reduces - in particular when the method is called `GetDeviceById`.

Comment: Unless you're using a weird variant of the language where you have to pay by the line, I'd strongly recommend you prefer familiarity and readability over terseness. The first snippet is "short enough" IMO and understandable.

Comment: I don't see any benefit whatsoever in such a one-liner. In fact: I'd probably make you break it up in two lines if I were to review such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want you can create something based on [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) + [deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct) + passing in a `Func`. For example:

```cs
// in case of using `new()` generic constraint both generic params should be specified
var (dao, device) = CreateAndInvoke<DeviceCommunicationDao, int>(d => d.GetDeviceById(123));

static (T, TResult) CreateAndInvoke<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> f) where T : new()
{
    var t = new T();
    return (t, f(t));
}
```

Or via providing factory:

```cs
var (dao, device) = CreateAndInvoke(() => new DeviceCommunicationDao(),d => d.GetDeviceById(123));

static (T, TResult) CreateAndInvoke<T, TResult>(Func<T> fact, Func<T, TResult> f) 
{
    var t = fact();
    return (t, f(t));
}
```

Or just passing an created instance:

```cs
var (dao, device) = InvokeAndReturnBoth(new DeviceCommunicationDao(), d => d.GetDeviceById(123));

static (T, TResult) InvokeAndReturnBoth<T, TResult>(T inst, Func<T, TResult> f)
    => (inst, f(inst));
```

Though I would not say that this is much more readable/convenient.

Comment: Nice approach, but as you said, I'd say it's even less readable.
Sadly, it does not create 2 separate variables. Tuples are ugly as well ;)

Comment: You cannot have the cake _and_ eat it.

Comment: @Cleo _"Tuples are ugly as well ;)"_ - completely disagree but it is opinionated =) You have asked how this can be done -  I can't think of any other options besides this one. It is up to you to decide if it suits your needs.